# How do I remove white space from Bartik?

Tags: theming, 8

I like to move the left hand side further left to remove the white space, as well as move the right hand side towards the right, so that the centre has more space. I like to remove line wrapping with entries and with the majority of my endusers using widescreen monitors it doesn't look that great.

[image: Screenshot of my site]

Essentially I like to move the left and right sidebars towards the edges of their respective edges so the centre can become wider. I tried using the inspector and grepping for the relevant CSS code to modify but none of it seems to work.  Nothing else has been modified it is out of the box Bartik theme with no extensions.

**Update**

```
.layout-container {

  max-width: 95%;  /* 860px */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media all and (min-width: 95%) {
.layout-container {
max-width: 95%;
 }   
}

/**
  * Main
  */
  .layout-main-wrapper {
   min-height: 300px;
  }
 .layout-main {
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 40px;
 }
```

This works if I edit the `/core/themes/bartik/css/layout.css` if I copy the theme and place it in the `/themes` folder it doesnt work.

[image: it fails]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not attempt to manually override and of Drupal's core files (or any other module or theme for that matter) because your changes will be overwritten during updates. So do not search for the CSS and attempt to alter it.

Make a copy of the bartik theme instead, move it to sites/all/themes and rename the folder and the `.info` file. Finally alter the info file to give your theme a new name.

All Bartik lay-out code can be found in [layout.css](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/themes/bartik/css/layout.css?h=7.x). So you will have to modify widths and margins there.

Finally, I wanted to make you aware of the [Responsive Bartik](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_bartik) theme which is already slightly wider for widescreen monitors, but also optimized for mobile phone usage. You might find it usefull to use that instead, or use it as a base theme for your modifications.

**Update for Drupal 8**

You have the [core/themes/bartik/css/layout.css](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/themes/bartik/css/layout.css?h=8.3.x) file where you have to alter the max-width for wide screens:

```
/**
 * Container
 */
.layout-container {
  max-width: 860px; /* <- This is the default width. */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media all and (min-width: 851px) { /* <- Bigger than this means it is a wide screen */
  .layout-container {
    max-width: 1290px; /* <- This is the max-width for wide screens. */
  }
}
```

Most of the CSS properties are defined in percents and so they should scale along.

Comment: I have Drupal 8, would Responsive Bartik 7 still work?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought the question was for Drupal 7. You can still copy and alter the theme though.

Comment: No worries, could have sworn I had said 8, but guess not.  There is quite a lot of files for css then on bartik8.  I will go with the copy and edit idea instead.  That being said, in `.layout-container` do i just change `max-width: 860px;` to something else?  I am familiar with css but nothing of this magnitude.

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Weird, soon as I copied the theme, even without making any changes to it, and activated it, the left and right hand side bars over left the centre content areas.  Not sure why, it is identical to the default core bartik, except it now lives in the user area, since i am not editing the `core/themes`, its in `/themes`.  I assume though, I change the max width to ... ? or just chante it to `max-width: 95%;`?

Comment: i am unable to get it to work if i cloned the theme but it works if i edit the actual default theme.  which works for me.

Comment: That will break every time you update Drupal, be aware of that. It should have worked to copy the theme folder and give it a different name (like `new_bartik`). Then alter all `bartik.*` files in the folder to `new_bartik.*` as well.

Comment: I did that, I had renamed everything bartik2, even undid all the changes to the original theme.  I cleared the cache each time.  Though that being said,. changing everything to 95% seemed to get the wideness I desired, but it widened the sidebars too, I just wanted them moved to allow more centre space.  I may just use newsflash theme and modify the colours to my needs.

Comment: Whatever works for you :)